# Read exit status from previous commands in a pipe

Tags: go, environment-variables, pipe, command-line-interface, exit-code

I am trying to detect if any command in a pipe sequence has failed before the execution of my application.

I am approaching a solution by reading `$PIPESTATUS` (bash) or `$pipestatus` (zsh) environment variables, which should contain an array with the exit codes of each command.

Sadly, I am not being able to retrieve these values using `os.Getenv`. This is a quick proof of concept:

```golang
package main

import (
  "os"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  fmt.Printf("$PIPESTATUS is /%v/\n", os.Getenv("PIPESTATUS"))
  fmt.Printf("$pipestatus is /%v/\n", os.Getenv("pipestatus"))
}
```

Which results in the following output:

```
$ true | false | go run read_pipestatus.go
$PIPESTATUS is //
$pipestatus is //
```

How can I make this approach work or alternatives ones?

Comment: `PIPESTATUS` isn't for use within your own process, (how could it change in the environment after it's been executed?) it's for piped commands executed by your shell. The pipeline is controlled by the shell, so you can only check it from the shell.

Comment: Great point, @JimB! Thanks for the explanation, you are completely right, that approach makes no sense. I will keep searching if there is a way to obtain the exit code of the previous commands in a pipe.